# Webservice overloading workaround

Tags: apex, webservices, method

according to the documentation we can't overload a webservice method. If I need a dynamic option but can only call one method what would be the best way to get this to work?

Comment: You need with dynamic number of argument it is not possible else you can  write different helper method to achieve that

Answer (score 1):

The overloading problem occurs because WSDL can't properly describe the same method with different parameters without causing issues on the API layer (as far as I know, *all* WSDL-based calls suffer this limitation, it's a "feature" of WSDL). The basic solution to this problem is a wrapper class:

## Wrapper

```
global class Parameters {
    webservice String stringParam;
    webservice Integer numParam;
}

...

webservice static Response myMethod(Parameters param) {
    ...
}
```

Note that not all parameters are required (they're `xsl:nillable`), but you'll have to do additional work to determine which parameters to use.